# How to host iOS8 Action extension in 3rd party web browser

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, ios8, ios8-extension, wkwebview

Let's suppose that i have implemented an iOS web browser, capable of bidirectional communication with Javascript in the webview. What i would have to do if i wanted **any** iOS8 Action extensions to work in it, as it does in Mobile Safari? There is no problem in telling the webview to execute functions on the mandated `ExtensionPreprocessingJS` object and get the callback result. But how do i even get hold of that `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` ? I haven't found any iOS8 API which would allow me to enumerate the eligible app extensions. The less getting hold of their `Info.plist`s and actually get the file out of the app extension's bundle content.

Through my test Action extension, i know that the whole `extensionContext.inputItems` ever given to the extension is just and only what [Apple Action extension doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1) says: a single `NSItemProvider` under `NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey`, providing a single `kUTTypePropertyList` with what the JS execution already returned. In other words, the JS must be known and executed even before `beginRequestWithExtensionContext` is called.

Do i miss something or is it really impossible for 3rd party apps to do the same as Mobile Safari? It would make kind of sense from app access security point of view, but still... the keywords here are "modularity" and "extensibility", right? Is Mobile Safari treated a more equal animal than vanilla UI/WKWebView animals here? I mean, `WKWebView` indeed has some neat new JS functionality (`evaluate` completion handler, `WKUserContentController`) but how do i wire it up with generic Action extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, most likely, not possible. An Action extension can have `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount` activation rule, which [some sources claim](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/09/23/ios8-day-by-day-day-29-safari-action-extension) is needed when you want to touch web pages with your extension. It wasn't needed for me, declaring  `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` is enough. **Anyway**, nobody knows what is it that you would need to put to controller's `activityItems` on the extension host side, the less what [UTI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008771) it should be categorized with. I have tried

- putting webview reference directly in the `activityItems` array. This works nicely for "primitive" types like `NSString` or `NSURL`, despite missing UTIs. But for `WKWebView` it results in runtime warning `Unknown activity items supplied`.
- creating `NSItemProvider` with the reference, guessing UTI with the most generic applicable `kUTTypeContent`. XCode protests the technique already with semantic warning, because `WKWebView` does not implement the required `<NSSecureCopying>` protocol. Unsurprisingly, doesn't do anything.

Last but not least, i found a [Chromium feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405894) for exactly what i want to achieve. There a 1Password developer **and** a LastPass primary developer conclude that the level of app extension integration as in Mobile Safari isn't possible in 3rd party iOS web browsers.

Bummer.

If anyone wants to keep trying, i have rigged my [iOS webview playground](https://github.com/pavel-zdenek/nsurlprotocol-testbed) with the Activity code. Feel free to fork.